# Javascript - debug via console.log

Tags: javascript, eslint, console.log

I have this part of code in js:

```
getResults() {
    let par = Object.keys(this.selected_options).map((key)=> {
        return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.selected_options[key]);
    }).join('&');
    console.log(par);
    this.search(par);
}

search(par){
    this.http.get('check?'+par)
    .then(response => this.helper.isJson(response.response) || [])
    .then(data => this.news = data)
    .catch(error => {
        let response = this.helper.isJson(error.response);
        let message = this.helper.getErrorMessage(error.statusCode, response);
    });
}
```

The problem is that console.log is not working anywhere. I need to debug it and check the content of response and data.

Even if I tried as you can see in my code to use console.log(par); it says unexpected console statement (no-console).

In the second part there is even no place to put console.log as the whole request is connected together with .then.

So how should I debug such code? I mean in the 2nd part I need to see the result of data and also response.

Even if I use

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(response);
```

at the end of the search method, it works not.

Comment: You can put a function in the `then`s. Eg, `.then(response => {console.log(response); return this.helper.isJson(response.response) || []})`

I mean, that's the same as what you do currently, but depending on what `this.helper.isJson` returns, it's probably not what you want to be doing...

Comment: Feel free to ignore the linter while debugging. If you disable the linter rule, what happens? Do you see log statements anywhere? Try putting one at the bottom of the last `.then` too

Comment: consider: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @Jamiec yes, thanks, it was a mistake with param.  Thank you dbramwell this way it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using inline lambda functions which can omit the `{` & `}` if there is just one statement. If you want more statements you can add them:

```
.then(response => this.helper.isJson(response.response) || [])
```

Can be

```
.then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       return this.helper.isJson(response.response) || []);
 })
```

Don't forget to add the `return` statement!